# What statistical impact of data aggregation if normal distribution becomes bimodal?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let us say that we have data which forms small groups, with a normal distribution within those groups.

We want to aggregate that data into bigger groups. But a possible result is that the distribution of the data within these bigger groups will start getting closer to a bimodal distribution (if the small groups are not very homogeneous).

When is it alright to keep the aggregated data, and when should we revert back to a higher level of desegregation? In other words, how can we measure the impact on statistical analysis of aggregating small, relatively heterogenous groups into bigger groups?

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on what kind of analysis you're doing. And how "big" the bigger groups are. Many kinds of statistical analysis are 'robust' against this kind of departure from normality. If the modes are clearly widely separated, you have to ask yourself whether it makes any sense at all to lump such disparate samples/populations together as one. Finding a CI for the pop mean height of US citizens probably makes sense. For male and female gorillas, maybe treat genders separately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll think on that then!